# OnClickListener is not working inside my adapter class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I looked at many solutions posted online but they couldn't solve my problem. Probably the adapter position is returning -1 but why?

```
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:439)
        at 
    com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.getSnapshot(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:70)
        at com.example.twitterclone.adapters.MyAdapter$TweetViewHolder.<init>(MyAdapter.kt:36)
        at com.example.twitterclone.adapters.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.kt:50)
        at com.example.twitterclone.adapters.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.kt:21)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
        at
```

**RecyclerViewAdapterCode:**

```
    class MyAdapter(
    options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Tweet>,
    private val clickInterface: ClickInterface
    ):FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Tweet, MyAdapter.TweetViewHolder>(options) {

    inner class TweetViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val profile =
            view.findViewById<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView>(R.id.userProfile)
        val tweet = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tweet)
        val like = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.totalLikes)
        val thumbsUp = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.thumbsUp)
        val name=view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tweetUserName)
        init {


                val tweetId=snapshots.getSnapshot(adapterPosition).get("tweetId")
                thumbsUp.setOnClickListener {
                    clickInterface.clickLike(tweetId.toString())
                }

        }


    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): TweetViewHolder {
        val viewHolder = TweetViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.post_tweets_item, parent, false)
        )



        return viewHolder
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(
        holder: TweetViewHolder,
        position: Int,
        model: Tweet
    ) {
        holder.tweet.text = model.content.toString()
        holder.like.text = model.likes.toString()
        UserDao().getUser(model.uid!!).get().addOnSuccessListener {
            holder.name.text = it.get("name").toString()
            Glide.with(holder.profile.context).load(it.get("profileUrl").toString())
                .into(holder.profile)
        }


    }
     }
```

**LayoutCode**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/userProfile"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tweetUserName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tweet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:id="@+id/thumbsUp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_thumb_up_24" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/totalLikes"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:id="@+id/comments"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_comment_24" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/totalComments"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint inside the `onClickListener` to see if it is really firing the onClick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adapterPosition` in the ViewHolder's init block is returning -1. So we just need to call `adapterPosition` in the listener which will solve the issue, since it would retrieve the position when the view holder is created and attached to the `recyclerview`. Setting any kind of listeners in the init block is a good approach since the `onCreateViewHolder` called only once to create a view holder but the `onBindViewHolder` called multiple times for the same view holder, so setting listeners in the `onBindViewHolder` would be redundant.

```
   init {

            thumbsUp.setOnClickListener {
                val tweetId=snapshots.getSnapshot(adapterPosition).get("tweetId")
                clickInterface.clickLike(tweetId.toString())
            }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Attache you onClickListener in onBindViewHolder

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(
            holder: TweetViewHolder,
            position: Int,
            model: Tweet
        ) {
            //your code of attaching data to view
            holder.thumbsUp.setOnClickListener{
              clickInterface.clickLike(model.tweetId.toString())
           }
         }
```

Reconsider your application architecture. As asking DAO for data inside RecyclerView.Adapter is quite strange approach

Comment: NO, don't do that. Attaching a listener inside a onbindviewholder is awful, because this will have a big performance impact!

Comment: adding click listner has performance impact? on what?

Comment: On the recyclerview of course. `OnBindViewHolder()` will be called multiple times, therefore the listener will also be attached multiple times. One should never do this and rather attach the listener in `OnCreateViewHolder()`

Comment: sorry but hahahaha. Big performance issue on calling once setOnClickListener in onBindViewHolder.  And as a comment to code where author is calling DAO for data in onBindViewHolder.  In this particular example it is even more unknown what is better, as we don't know what author is doing with method snapshots.getSnapshot(adapterPosition).get("tweetId"). And I think that is bigger performance issue that calling setOnClickListener on every bind :P

Comment: Well, part of your answer is right. But just because the author does horrible things inside his onBindViewHolder, you don't have to do the same :P

Comment: still you are not even close to true. Try to check how much time/memory takes setting onClickListener and reconsider 

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I'd expect `adapterPosition` in your `getSnapshot`call in the `ViewHolder`'s init block is returning -1. As far as I'm aware, [all the adapter position getters return the position of the last requested item for display.](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAdapterPosition()) But when you're first creating `ViewHolder`s, nothing has bound to the adapter yet (it's all still in the setup phase), so its default `position` is probably **-1**.

Basically the way `RecyclerView`s work is this - you define these `ViewHolder` objects which are basically things that display data for each item. Instead of having one for each item in the list, the adapter creates a handful of them (enough to fill the visible area and a couple either side), and then **recycles** them by moving them around when they're out of view, and updates their contents to represent a different item.

`onCreateViewHolder` is what the adapter calls to create those container objects. It's where you inflate the layout and usually do `findViewById` on the views so you have a reference to them, and you can just set a `TextView`'s text instead of having to fnd the view every time you want to update it.

`onBindViewHolder` is what gets called when you need to update a `ViewHolder` with a different item's info. This is where you actually do all the setting of data, changing images and whatever, updating click listeners if necessary.

Basically you shouldn't be using `adapterPosition` in your `ViewHolder`'s `init` block, because that gets called once, when the object is constructed. Not only do you not have a meaningful position at that point, but isn't that something you'll want to update often, as the position changes? That's what `onBindViewHolder` is for! It has the position passed in and everything. That's the method where you set state