# (android) How to select singleItem in Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

Hello.

I want to implement single item selection function in `RecyclerView`

`RecyclerView`'s item is made up of `TextView` only.

When i clicked items, i want to change `TextView`'s background color

I want to click only single item.

But items are clicked only multiple

When I click the first item and then the second item, the background color of the first item should be changed.

This is i wanted.

However i can't change the `Text` of the previous item in 'Adapter'.

I don't know how to get previous selected `View`.

How should i do?

Adapter.java

```
public class RoutineListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoutineListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
//    ArrayList<RoutineListModel> items;
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;

    public void addItems(List<String> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.routine_list_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setItem(items.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView routine;
        boolean isSelected;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            routine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.routine_list);
            routine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(isSelected == false) {
                        routine.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.light_green_dark));
                        isSelected = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        routine.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                        isSelected = false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private void setItem(String item) {
            routine.setText(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can keep a selected item position and whenever we select something from recyclerview, you can use that position variable to see if the background should be set or not.

Comment: You can use the [recyclerview-selection library](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview-custom#select) and call [SelectionPredicates.createSelectSingleAnything()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/selection/SelectionPredicates#createSelectSingleAnything())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewHolder's multiple instances are being created, so each instance has its own `isSelected` property and its value.

But what you need a singe common variable for all `viewholder` instance to refere it, hence the `selectedPosition` in the outer class, so it is only one, and when you click you set the current adapter position value to and with that you must notify the adapter, which will trigger to call the `onBindViewHolder` for all items and in the `setItem()` you can put up what you want to set background of views on basis of whatever conditions.

```
public class RoutineListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoutineListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

//    ArrayList<RoutineListModel> items;
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;
    int selectedPosition=-1;
//nothing selected initially

    public void addItems(List<String> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.routine_list_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setItem(items.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView routine;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            routine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.routine_list);
            routine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    selectedPosition=getAdapterPosition();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }

        private void setItem(String item) {
                    if(selectedPosition== getAdapterPosition()) {
                        routine.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.light_green_dark));
                    }
                    else {
                        routine.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    }

            routine.setText(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't work..There is no error. But color doesn't change

Comment: I missed `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: haha.. I realized that there were no monkeys...thank you so much

Comment: hey I'm really sorry, but can I ask you one more question?

Comment: It's about `onBindViewHolder()`, doesn't it bind data only once in the first time?
So I thought it was only called once at first. So `setItem()` too.
But when I look at the `setItem()` in your code, it seems like it's called every time I click it..

Comment: Yes, only `onCreateViewHolder` called once per item, but `onBindViewHolder` called multiple times when you scroll the `recyclerview`  when you `notify` the adapter.  And yes when you click I called notify, hence it will be called.

Comment: um you mean when i scrolled computer and when i clicked items. `onBindViewHolder()` is called and redraw(re-bind) everytime right?

+) What is 'trigger' 's mean in your answer?.. because i can't eng well...

Comment: yes, when you scroll it is done by the android and depends upon like if it has bound view or it needs to rebound, but when you click it is done by your code since you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged` to notify the adapter.

Comment: For best practice on how to set listeners for recyclerview items visit here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65548939/9701793

Comment: oh i understand. When i scrolled `Rectclerview`, onBindViewHolder() is called automatically at `Android`, And When I click or another event occurs, I have to let you know directly using `notifyDataSetChanged`. right?

and i read your link. Thank you

Comment: yes, since we need the background of the current item/ and the rest items to change accordingly, which will be done when the `onBindViewHolder` will be called